# Validar delete no controller, retornar html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho meu cadastro, que foi feito usando Scallfold do visual studio
Na minha view:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
        </div>
    }
```

E no meu controller:

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
    db.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Como eu valido a exclusão se já existe registro com esse cliente? Como retorno para View usando html helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque na View:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```cs
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Include(c => c.Registros).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    if (cliente.Registros.Count > 0) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cliente possui registros pendentes.");
        return View("Delete", cliente)
    }

    db.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Não aparece a mensagem de erro na view...

Comment: @Rod Você colocou o `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`?

Comment: Acho que te falei bobagem. O `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` tem que ser dentro do `Html.BeginForm`.

Comment: Exatamente dessa forma, não aparece a msg na View, tentei até com ValidationMessage("Erro") também não aparece

Comment: @Rod Revi algumas coisas e o `RedirectToAction` não considera o resultado da validação. Atualizei minha resposta.